# MySQL optimise slow UNION query in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, optimization

I have the following code in my stored procedure, which basically joins the SQL text into one big query in `while` loop, then executes it. I have 7 `UNION ALL` statements from 7 **different** tables with some input parameters (`table_name1...7`, `start_date`, `end_date`):

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_max INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 58; 
DECLARE v_counter INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1; 
SET @sql_text = '';
WHILE v_counter < v_max DO
-- Build SQL string
SET @sql_text = CONCAT(@sql_text, 
CONCAT(' SELECT 
(SELECT i.name FROM instrument i WHERE i.id =',v_counter,' LIMIT 1) AS Instrument,
(SELECT AVG(p.ask-p.bid) AS avg_spread
FROM ',table_name1,' p
WHERE p.instrument_id=',v_counter,' AND  FROM_UNIXTIME(p.system_datetime/1000000) BETWEEN \'',start_date,'\' AND \'',end_date,'\') AS One

,

(SELECT AVG(p.ask-p.bid) AS avg_spread
FROM ', table_name2,' p
WHERE p.instrument_id=',v_counter,' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.system_datetime/1000000) BETWEEN \'',start_date,'\' AND \'', end_date,'\') AS Two

,

(SELECT AVG(p.ask-p.bid) AS avg_spread
FROM ',table_name3,' p
WHERE p.instrument_id=',v_counter,' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.system_datetime/1000000) BETWEEN \'', start_date,'\' AND \'',end_date,'\') AS Three

/* ... more unions here ...*/
,

(SELECT AVG(p.ask-p.bid) AS avg_spread
FROM ',table_name7,' p
WHERE p.instrument_id=',v_counter,' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.system_datetime/1000000) BETWEEN \'', start_date,'\' AND \'',end_date,'\') AS Seven UNION ALL ')

);


SET v_counter=v_counter+1; 

END WHILE;

-- Remove extra UNION ALL from SQL string
SET @sql_text = LEFT(@sql_text,LENGTH(@sql_text) - LENGTH(' UNION ALL'));
-- SELECT LEFT(@sql_text,LENGTH(@sql_text) - LENGTH(' UNION ALL'));

-- Prepare and execute statement
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

I wonder is there any way to optimise this query (the seven tables contain on average 3.5 million records each), the execution time is between 6 and 25 minutes? Tables are MyISAM, identical, here is their structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices_all_2016_06_13_5` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `instrument_id` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `ask` DECIMAL(12,6) NOT NULL,
    `bid` DECIMAL(12,6) NOT NULL,
    `system_datetime` DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `Index 3` (`instrument_id`) USING HASH,
    INDEX `Index 4` (`system_datetime`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
AUTO_INCREMENT=3882184
;
```

**EDIT:** This is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "PRIMARY"   \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"9" "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"8" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "64566" "Using where"
"7" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "71061" "Using where"
"6" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "43979" "Using where"
"5" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "69852" "Using where"
"4" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "117355"    "Using where"
"3" "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "70672" "Using where"
"2" "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"10"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"18"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"17"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "52505" "Using where"
"16"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "68781" "Using where"
"15"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "40055" "Using where"
"14"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "32054" "Using where"
"13"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "57465" "Using where"
"12"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "33265" "Using where"
"11"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"19"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"27"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"26"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "75411" "Using where"
"25"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "91574" "Using where"
"24"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "47560" "Using where"
"23"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "80731" "Using where"
"22"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "139225"    "Using where"
"21"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "109131"    "Using where"
"20"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"28"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"36"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"35"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "67288" "Using where"
"34"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "83522" "Using where"
"33"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "46650" "Using where"
"32"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "50401" "Using where"
"31"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "73280" "Using where"
"30"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "50836" "Using where"
"29"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"37"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"45"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"44"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "59256" "Using where"
"43"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "54092" "Using where"
"42"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "41561" "Using where"
"41"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "51928" "Using where"
"40"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "64368" "Using where"
"39"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "60471" "Using where"
"38"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"46"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"54"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"53"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "59213" "Using where"
"52"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "56071" "Using where"
"51"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "47653" "Using where"
"50"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "46033" "Using where"
"49"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "56180" "Using where"
"48"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "47262" "Using where"
"47"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" \N
"55"    "UNION" \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "No tables used"
"63"    "SUBQUERY"  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
"62"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "69552" "Using where"
"61"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "100487"    "Using where"
"60"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "78156" "Using where"
"59"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "105721"    "Using where"
"58"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "128156"    "Using where"
"57"    "SUBQUERY"  "p" "ref"   "Index 3"   "Index 3"   "1" "const" "114533"    "Using where"
"56"    "SUBQUERY"  "i" "const" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "const" "1" ...
```

Comment: Try to `EXPLAIN` your query and update the question with its output. Is there any reason the tables are not InnoDB?

Comment: Also refine your query so that it can use indexes: compare fields, not anything computed from them. `FROM_UNIXTIME(field)` cannot use indexes.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` added. Tables are MyISAM because of the performance considerations

Comment: Can you post also the full query? Why are you using `AVG()`? I don't see there and `GROUP BY`, what are you averaging? Without `GROUP BY` you get a lot of same rows. Try running parts of your query alone to confirm they are doing what you want.

Comment: Currently I'm testing with modification of input dates - without usage of `FROM_UNIXTIME`, the idea of `AVG` is that I need averages from column values in those tables (basically values are prices with 5 decimal points)

Comment: I think, beside of what was already said, a compound index may improve  the performance. `INDEX \`Index z\` (\`instrument_id\`, \`system_datetime\`)`

Comment: Adding compound index improved query execution time by 25%

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(p.system_datetime/1000000)
      BETWEEN \'', start_date,'\' AND \'', end_date,'\'
```

Don't hide a column in a function; indexes cannot be used.  Instead:

```
p.system_datetime
      BETWEEN 1000000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(\'', start_date,'\')
          AND 1000000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(\'', end_date,'\')
```

Some reason for using `DECIMAL(20,0)` instead of `DECIMAL(20,6)`, thereby avoiding the `1000000`?  Also note that new MySQLs have `DATETIME(6)` and `TIMESTAMP(6)` that give you the desired microsecond resolution.

Once you have reformulated the query, `p` will need this for more efficiency:

```
INDEX(instrument_id, system_datetime)
```

Furthermore, if these tables have identical structure, it is *probably* better to have *one* table, not many.  It would probably need an extra column to distinguish what "table" each row belongs to.  You seem to be doing "partitioning via table names" (`prices_all_2016_06_13_5`, etc).

Also, switching to InnoDB, and designing the 'right' `PRIMARY KEY`, probably 'composite', will give you another performance boost because of "clustering".

`PARTITIONing` may or may not be worth doing.  (It often buys no performance.)

I need to better understand what your queries are in order to further advise.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm doing partitioning via table names, tables are exactly the same as structure, but they become extremely large for 24 hours period - about 20 million records, so the search (which is important) is very slow after couple of days. Resolved the issue by removing entire `FROM_UNIXTIME` condition. Thank you for response.